# Write large data with WriteLineAsync in a using block

Tags: c#, stream, append, dispose, using

Can the following code cause an error, if `WriteLineAsync` is not finished with writing, but the `using` term tries to dispose the `writer` stream?

For example:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(fileName))
{ 
    writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
}
```

What does happen, if i write very large data, which may takes a few seconds?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, stream will  be disposed of before the task has completed.

You should either await the task returned by `WriteLineAsync` or write to the file synchronously instead, using `WriteLine`.

Comment: Ok, than `WriteLine` seems to be more straight forward, or not?

Comment: @BendEg If you mean "easy to implement", yes. Whether or not that meets your requirements, that's another question.